# Proving an algebraic result.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

If I have an algebraic result, how would you prove it?

e.g:

Prove;

$$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} =\frac{x-y} {\sqrt{x}  +\sqrt{y}}, \quad for \, \, x, y\gt 0.$$

Are you allowed to assume it's true and show $LHS \equiv RHS?$ 
As  $x-y=x-y $?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your bottom question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @GitGud What the OP wants to do is assume the equations are equal, multiply both sides by $\sqrt x+\sqrt y$, and then show $x-y=x-y$ in order to prove the original equation.

Comment: @GitGud so I assumed that thw statement was true, and multiplied the expression by $(\sqrt{x}  +\sqrt{y}) $. This meant that the left hand side is equal to the right hand side (after expanding the LHS).

Comment: @NobleMushtak That's my interpretation too.  But I want the OP to confirm it and write it more clearly.

Comment: @Gurjinder When you go about reaching the equality $x-y=x-y$ from the starting equality, what you do is prove the equivalence between the former and the latter. Pretty much by definition of "equivalence", proving one, proves the other and since $x-y=x-y$ is trivially true, you're done. One important aspect is to be sure that you're actually working with equivalences and not just going in one direction. Alternatively, (see Noble's answer), you can just take the LHS of what you want to prove and get to the RHS by a clever enough arithmetic manipulation.

Comment: @GitGud understood, cheers.

Comment: Hint: $x = (\sqrt{x})^2$

Answer (score 3):

In proofs of equations, it is not OK to assume the expressions are equal and prove $LHS=RHS$ because this can lead to mistakes such as showing $-x=x$ by squaring both sides. Usually, what I do is the first time, I assume the expressions are equal and show $LHS=RHS$. Then, in order to make sure there are no fallacies in my proof, I 
start with the $LHS=RHS$ I got at the end of my work on the first time and work backwards to the original equation.

In this case, what I suggest you do is start with the right-hand side, factor the $x-y$ into $(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)(\sqrt x-\sqrt y)$, and then cancel with the denominator to get the left-hand side. This shows how the right-hand side equals the left-hand side only by using valid algebraic expression substitutions without assuming they're equal.

Comment: You have an awesome name. I'm refraining from up voting your answer until I understand exactly what the OP is asking, but it seems on point.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do it without the square roots :

$$a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}\iff (a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$$

and this is only high school algebra...

Comment: ... while it's worth to consider the case $a=-b$...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Impossible, as the original question has square roots everywhere, and thus all the numbers must be positive...not even zero is allowed.

Comment: Well, just nitpicking, in your formulation with $a$’s and $b$’s its considerable.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, I know...yet that was only a hint. The OP shall come up with some work of his/her own.